# Confused about __init__.py and importing

Tags: python

So I have a directory setup like so:

```
some_dir/
  foo/
    bar/
      test.py
  src/
    __init__.py
    data/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
```

I want to import `utils.py` from my test.py module.

```
import sys.path
sys.path.append("../../")
from src import data
data.utils // this throws an error AttributeError: module 'src.data' has no attribute 'utils'
```

But when I do:

```
import sys.path
sys.path.append("../../")
from src.data import utils
```

Everything works, why is this?

Comment: `utils` has never been imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `from src.data import utils` will import `utils.py`, so everything is ok.

b) `from src import data` will just import the `data package`, never import `utils.py`, if you want, you need add explicit import in `__init__.py` under the folder `data`, something like follows:

*1) If need to support both python3 & python2:*

**__init__.py:**

```
import src.data.utils # absolute import
```

Or:

**__init__.py:**

```
from . import utils # relative import
```

*2) If just need to support python2, make it simple:*

**__init__.py:**

```
import utils
```

Then, when package imported, the `__init__.py` under this package will also be executed.